# Collision Player - Enemies (Shooting Game - Swift 4 -SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, game-physics

I'm working on a Shooter Game coded in Swift 4, using SKSpriteNodes.

I've tried to make my game stop when an enemy, and to show the GameOverScene, but it does not work, and I don't understand why.

I've used the same kind of functions for the collision of the projectiles and the enemies, and it works well.

Here's my code, from the GameScene :

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None      : UInt32 = 0
    static let All       : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let Monster   : UInt32 = 0b1       // 1
    static let Projectile: UInt32 = 0b10      // 2
    static let Player    : UInt32 = 0b01
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.5)
    player.zPosition = 2

    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size) // 1
    player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // 2
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster // 3
    player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile // 4
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None // 5

    addChild(player) 
}

    func addMonster() {

    // Create sprite
    let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "monster")
    monster.zPosition = 2

    monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: monster.size) // 1
    monster.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // 2
    monster.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster // 3
    monster.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile // 4
    monster.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None // 5

    // Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
    let actualY = random(min: monster.size.height/2, max: size.height - monster.size.height/2)

    // Position the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
    // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
    monster.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + monster.size.width/2, y: actualY)

    // Add the monster to the scene
    addChild(monster)

    // vitesse augmentée
    let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(1), max: CGFloat(4))

     // Create the actions
    let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -monster.size.width/2, y: actualY), duration: TimeInterval(actualDuration))
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    monster.run(SKAction.sequence([ actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
}

    func ennemyCollidesWithPlayer(monster: SKSpriteNode, player: SKSpriteNode){
    print("Game Over")

    let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
    let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: false)
    self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    //collision player et enemy
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Player != 0)) {
        if let player = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode, let
            monster = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode {
            ennemyCollidesWithPlayer(monster: monster, player: player)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest setting a breakpoint and stepping through the logical tests to see what the comparison values are.

Comment: in your didMove you are calling the object "player" but setting the category to monster, so I am going to assume that that is the monster. can you included the code where you create the players physicsBody.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on with the code posted.*"I've tried to make my game stop when an enemy, and to show the GameOverScene"*, very little of your code posted is helpful. What makes your game stop? Where's the code for that **and** to show the game over scene? Hard to not vote to close (I haven't but someone did) but also hard to be of any help with what you've posted. Don't post what works. Don't post what doesn't work - and not point out the specific line that fails where you think it does. But also, remember we wish to duplicate the issue - not copy your code.

Comment: I think the problem was some simple errors, like the calling of "Monster" in the player's PhysicsCategory, and not having the same zPosition's for the Player and the Monsters. This question can be closed, the solution must not be complicated to find.

Comment: it's not fair to those that spend the time to help you for you to opt to close the question after they've given you the answer

Comment: I was saying that in response to the comment of dfd, in fact, I've seen later that some parts of my code that I had added in my question were gone. And that moment, there were no answer. But now, I've seen your answer, and I'm trying it out.
I'm not going to close it anymore, don't worry. I've edited my question to make sure it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

categoryBitMask is the classification of the physics body on the current object it also the identifier used when checking the type of physics body

contactBitMask is setting the which objects will report in didBegin upon contact

both your player and monster have the same categoryBitMask set

change player to type `PhysicsCategory.Player`

you will also need to set the player contactBitMask to

```
contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
```